# SOAP Security WSEE & WSU PHP Request

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I have been racking my brains and have been googling all day but have come to nothing, I am using an API that uses the 
http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd and http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd and signature values here is an example of the header i am trying to send in my request

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-91553746A32F6E86A9152119298361091">REMOVED</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
     <ds:Signature Id="SIG-91553746A32F6E86A9152119298361195" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ser ser1 soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
     </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#id-91553746A32F6E86A9152119298361094">
        <ds:Transforms>
           <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
              <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ser ser1" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
           </ds:Transform>
           </ds:Transforms>
           <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
           <ds:DigestValue>HG6Tb/IJfVWj4ZC1guDubIrFk4nw1IgoPavDqkSCrLM=</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
     </ds:SignedInfo>
     <ds:SignatureValue></ds:SignatureValue>
     <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-91553746A32F6E86A9152119298361092">
        <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-91553746A32F6E86A9152119298361093">
           <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-91553746A32F6E86A9152119298361091" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
     </ds:Signature>
  </wsse:Security>
```

Is there someone out there that can help me build this using SOAP request in PHP.... i'm stumped.